# JQuery/bootstrap loading and appending a table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Got a massive multi-section form so decided to create a tbody and add sections to it. The following code and variations I try are not doing as I was expecting. Each section.html is a , e.g.

```
  <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">
```

But each section added tends to replace the previous sections. I was expecting to add a number of table rows - e.g. append() - the way I am using it - is not working.. Any clues on how I can append chunks of html "`<tr>...</tr>`" to a `<tbody>`

Many thanks

Kevin

Code (not appending):

```
<legend>New Landlord License</legend>
<div class="control-group">
<div class="bs-example">
  <table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-bottom:0px;">
     <tbody id="tb" name="tb">
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#tb').load("./section1.html")
       $('#tb').append().load("./section2.html");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#tb').load("./section1.html");
   $.get("./section2.html", function(data){
      $('#tb').append(data);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you just loop through an array contaand append them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pages = [1, 5, 7, 12];
    for(var i = 0; i < pages.length;i++){
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: "./section" + i +".html",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#tbls').append(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks and I tried it several times but the load order is not always sequential (e.g. 2,3,4,5,1 ... 1,2,3,4,5 ... 2,3,4,5,1 ..). That does obviously look much neater but it seems like the "ajax success:" where the code continues to execute before the result is returned so its getting the next section on some occasions before finishing the previous block.

Comment: @KevinY updated my answer. Also since it's using `async:false` this will pause the browser loading until it's finished meaning they'll load into `#tbls` in order.

Answer (score 0):

Want to first say a big thanks to Beginner for putting me on track. I had to create a variation of my original by putting separate tables in the section code and not table rows. 
I used Beginner's help to solve this and put completed section below. The reason for that is because I stumbled upon a timing issue which could result in the sections appearing in the wrong order.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.get("./section1.html",function(data){
   $('#tbls').append(data);
   $.get("./section2.html",function(data){
      $('#tbls').append(data);
      $.get("./section3.html",function(data){
         $('#tbls').append(data);
         $.get("./section4.html",function(data){
            $('#tbls').append(data);
            $.get("./section5.html",function(data){
               $('#tbls').append(data);
             });
          });
       });
    });
  });
});
</script>
```